# Synchronization between master and backup server

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, duplication

I am searching for an option to synchronize data between production server and backup server automatically. Does somebody know a method, how I can do this:

- if I delete, insert or update a record it should update it should do the same action for the backup server
- if I select some entries it should select it from the primary server
- if the primary server is not available it should select, insert, update and delete on the backup server
- if the backup server is available again, it should write the data back to the primary sql server

Comment: We've used XOSoft's WanSync HA for this scenario - see http://www.rdtsolutions.com/pdf/wansyncha_data.pdf. However, if you don't have specific expertise in this area, and you are building and designing a production database system that people rely upon, I'd seriously consider getting additional help.

Comment: @mjeOsX what version of sql server are you using ?

Comment: Is the goal fault tolerance against a single point of hardware failure, duplication of data in two locations, or both?

Comment: If you have SQL Server Standard edition or higher and version 2008 or higher (you haven't specified in your question) then [Database Mirroring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189852.aspx) might be a solution, but note that it is a feature that will be removed in some future version of SQL Server. THe replacement feature is [AlwaysOn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33f2f2d0-79e0-4107-9902-d67019b826aa) but that requires SQL Server 2012 Standard edition or higher and also requires Enterprise Edition of Windows Server 2008 or STandard Edition or higher of Windows Server 2012.